# Positioned Fix Div to the Right Side of a Div and hold it in the wrapper

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a middle div that is controlled by two divs as buttons which are in the right side and in the left side of that middle div.
TO make these two divs as control buttons, they have to be in the fixed positions. The problem is I want theses two fixed divs wrapped in the wrapper div which its width is 80% and has auto margins, so that these two divs will stay in the sides of the 'middle div' when the window is scaled.

Here is the script that make these two divs as control buttons:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#right").click(function () { 
       var leftPos = $('.DivDataMain').scrollLeft();
       $(".DivDataMain").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 250}, 800);
  });   

       $("#left").click(function () { 
       var leftPos2 = $('.DivDataMain').scrollLeft();
       $(".DivDataMain").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos2 - 250}, 800);
  });   
       });
```

And here is the css that SHOULD make these two divs have to be  in the sides of the middle div:

```
.DivDataMain {
     width:100%;
     overflow:hidden;
     display:block; 
     background:#000; 
     height:400px; 
     margin:auto;
     position: relative;
}

#left {
     width:60px;
     overflow:hidden;
     display:block;
     background:rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5); 
     height:200px;
     float:left; 
     clear:none; 
     position:fixed; 
     z-index:2;}

#right {
    width:60px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    background:rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5); 
    height:200px;
    clear:right;
    right: 0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:3;}

#midleBody {
   width:auto;
   overflow:hidden;
   display:block;
   background:#CFC;
   height:200px;
   float:left; 
   clear:none; 
   position:fixed; 
   z-index:1;
}
```

And then here is the demo: [Left Div & Right Div overlap](http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/UHmJ2/4/)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want...

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/MusGf/)

A couple of things:

1. For the positioning of the right div, I couldn't think of any other way to do it using fixed positioning without using calc.  That means that this will not work in IE8 (hope that's not too big of a deal).
2. I fixed your jQuery.  You want to scroll the content of the midleBody not the DivDataMain.
3. The mini reset (the * bit in the css) is not required per se, but because fixed elements are positioned relative to the viewport, not the nearest positioned ancestor, the calculation for positioning the right div will be off if you have any margin/padding on the containing element of the DivDataMain div.
4. I had to also change the source order in your markup to get this to work.
5. Personally, I would think about a different approach.  This seems incredibly fragile to me and I don't like the calc option in this particular case because there is no fallback.  Maybe I'll have a think on it with a beer and get back to you with a proposal for something else.

Meanwhile here is the working update to you layout/code/markup.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="DivDataMain">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
    <div id="midleBody">
        <p>The content of the midle body content of the midle body The content of the midle bodycontent of the midle body The content of the midle bodycontent of the midle body The content of the midle body</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.DivDataMain {
    width:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    background:#000;
    height:400px;
    margin:auto;
}
#left, #right {
    width:60px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    height:200px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#right {
    left: calc(90% - 60px);
}
#midleBody {
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background:#CFC;
    height:200px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#right").click(function () {
         var leftPos = $('#midleBody').scrollLeft();
         $("#midleBody").animate({
             scrollLeft: leftPos + 250
         }, 800);
     });

     $("#left").click(function () {
         var leftPos2 = $('#midleBody').scrollLeft();
         $("#midleBody").animate({
             scrollLeft: leftPos2 - 250
         }, 800);
     });
 });
```

Comment: You are brilliant..., this has been perfect for me... I have been thinking to use only a table with three columns, which are in the right and the left columns will be the buttons. But the markup for the table is a little annoying for me. Anyway, thanks for your help, I hope you will be willing to help me again next time.

Comment: I am just aware that this scrolling function doesn't work on chrome. Can you help me out with this, please?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  It seems to work fine in Chrome for me.  Of course, I'm testing on a MAC using the latest version of Chrome, so it could be possible that you're experiencing something different than me.